# Stationary Background, Moving Foreground Website

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio, web

So I have been working on a website using the .NET framework and would like to make the background style look a little something like it does at [bons.me](http://www.bons.me). As you can see when you scroll it background stays in the same position, however as you scroll the part of which you see changes. 
Anyone know how I would go about doing this? Would it be something in css or ...? I'm rather new to web development, but it would also be just as much of a help if you could just point me in a direction or tell me what this is called so I could google it.

Comment: What have you tried?  You're going to find that people on SO won't be all that willing to help if you haven't tried to accomplish this first yourself.  Maybe review this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This deals with the css property `background-position: fixed`. David Walsh has a good article describing the technique [here](http://davidwalsh.name/parallax).